# how to cast value of type nssingleobjectarrayi to 'nsdictionary swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to parse the response but it gives me **Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x7fff87b2af68) to 'NSString' (0x7fff87beba38)** this error.
my response is

format:[
{
"a":"b",
"c":"d"
}
]

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have single object array that is already dictionary

check this

```
let array = [ { "a":"b", "c":"d" } ]

let dictionary = array[0]
```

output : "a":"b", "c":"d"

where a and c is key and b and d is value